# How to convert duration into '%H:%M:%S.%f' time format, not in days

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to convert days to hours, minutes, seconds

```
def get_working_hours(self, obj):
    return datetime.strptime(str(obj.working_hours), '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
```

ValueError: time data '1 day, 7:06:38.340741' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: keep it a `timedelta` object.

The `obj.working_hours` is a [**`timedelta`** object [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Indeed:

```
>>> str(timedelta(days=1, hours=7, minutes=6, seconds=38, microseconds=340741))
'1 day, 7:06:38.340741'
```

Here the total number of hours is thus 31. You can not represent that with a `time` object. You probably should just keep it a timedelta. You can for example calculate the number of hours with:

```
>>> td.total_seconds()//3600  # hours
31.0
>>> (td.total_seconds() //60) % 60  # minutes
6.0
>>> td.total_seconds() % 60  # seconds
38.340741000007256
```

But a `time` object can only have time in the range of `00:00:00.000000` to `23:59:59.999999`. So you can not use a `time` object here.